# Repaginate PDF file to print a book

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I would like to prepare a PDF file for print using linux tools like PDFjam, psnup, ... 
The PDF consits of 24 single pages in A4 which are ordered as they would be consumed by the reader. For print I need to combine two of these A4 pages each on A3 pages such that, when the pages are printed two-sided and stacked on top of each other (in the order in which they appear in the new file) and stapled in their middle, they form a book which can be consumed by the reader in the correct order of the original PDF file.
In principle I could burst the PDF file and - by hand - create a latex file which includes the individual pages in the correct order. However I guess that this is a common problem and wonder if there is a tool such as the ones mentioned above or a switch which achieves this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool `pdfbook` (which seems to belong to pdfjam) does what is needed. In fact for the described case

```
pdfbook [file]
```

will repaginate portrait A4 pages on landscape A3 pages. To rotate the pages of the new file to portrait `pdf90` may be used. `pdfjam` allowes to change the paper-size (in order to account for print-margins).